# Why is the libindicator reporting all scroll event signals as UP?

Tags: application-development, indicator, debugging

I am trying to investigate [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-application/+bug/1075152); the gist is, if you have a Unity application indicator, and you scroll over it, the scroll event is always 'up', even if you scroll down.

Here is a sample Python script which creates an app indicator.  Run it, then mouseover the indicator (the Firefox icon) and scroll up and down.  The output is always:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, AppIndicator3

if __name__ == "__main__":
    menu = Gtk.Menu()
    quit = Gtk.MenuItem("Quit")
    quit.connect("activate", Gtk.main_quit)
    menu.append(quit)
    menu.show_all()

    def scroll(ind, steps, direction):
    print steps, direction
    if direction != Gdk.ScrollDirection.UP:
        print "Things seem ok"

    indicator = AppIndicator3.Indicator.new('testscroll', '', AppIndicator3.IndicatorCategory.APPLICATION_STATUS)
    indicator.set_status(AppIndicator3.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
    indicator.set_icon("/usr/share/pixmaps/firefox.png")
    indicator.connect("scroll-event", scroll)
    indicator.set_menu(menu)
    Gtk.main()
```

I can see that the signal is being [defined here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~indicator-applet-developers/libindicator/trunk.13.10/view/head:/libindicator/indicator-object.c#L202) but I cannot see where the scroll event is actually being emitted.

Where does the scroll event signal get emitted?  Where in the code would the 'bug' likely originate and incorrectly report a direction of up? (I am new to Ubuntu development, so apologies if something is dead obvious)

Comment: The signal is emitted from the indicator-applet (in unity, services/panel-service.c, or the old indicator-applet code src/applet-main.c). But the bug isn't there, it works fine from C: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5863471/ . It is likely a bug in the gobject introspection or the python bindings specifically.

Comment: Interesting to know that it works in C! Where would I find the python bindings?  I'm hoping to narrow it down and hopefully fix the bug myself.

Comment: It should either be in the python bindings (pygobject source package) or in the gobject-introspection annotations in libappindicator. I notice the Gtk.ResponseType enum works correctly in the 'response' signal for Gtk.Dialog, but they only annotate it as a gint, whereas 'scroll-event' is annotated as Gtk.ScrollDirection. So the easier fix may be to change the annotations, while the harder fix might be to figure out how to do enums from callbacks in the python bindings (if that is indeed the problem).

Comment: I'm also being bitten by this bug for my application Variety. I reported it to Gnome's bugzilla for the pygobject project: 
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=732470